# How can I ask matlab to give me the value of y if I input the value of x?

Tags: matlab, graph, graphing, points

I already have my xy graph using the line graph. What troubles me is how can I ask matlab to give me the value of y if I give the value of x. That is, the corresponding value of y when I give x in the line I have in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want to do is [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Say your x and y values that you used for plotting are stored in `xData` and `yData`, respectively.

Then, you find a value `y` that corresponds to a value `x` using [INTERP1](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html)

```
y = interp1(xData,yData,x);
```

By default, `interp1` interpolates linearly, that is, it returns the values as if the dots in the plot were connected by straight lines. If you want a smoother interpolation, you'd use

```
y = interp1(xData,yData,x,'cubic');
```