# Find the X value from a graph, created using pchip, given the Y value. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, interpolation

I would like to generate the `X` value using a corresponding random `Y` value, these random values are within the range of `Y`,  from a graph which i have created using the `pchip` function, but i want the generated `X` value to stay within a specific range.

My code:

```
samples=10
r=rand(samples,1)
Y=[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1];
x=12.5:45:327.5;
angle=pchip(y,x,r);
```

Output:

```
angle = 

1.0e+03 *

   -0.1392
   -3.3718
   -3.4856
   -3.2264
   -0.5284
   -0.8114
   -2.2368
   -0.0804
   -2.9240
   -1.9510
```

I would like the values to lie between -12.5-360 and I believe I could use something like this:

```
Y=[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1];
x=12.5:45:327.5;
xi=-12.5:360;
angle=pchip(y,xi,x);
```

But I cant then get it to generate the required `X` value from the given `Y` value. 
I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
samples=10
r=rand(samples,1)
Y=[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1];
xi=-12.5:360;
x=12.5:45:327.5;
angle=pchip(y,xi,x,r);
```

I have looked at the [mathworks pchip article](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html) and other mathworks articles but they don't seem to solve my problem and also looked at this stackoverflow article [How can I ask matlab to give me the value of y if I input the value of x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618067/how-can-i-ask-matlab-to-give-me-the-value-of-y-if-i-input-the-value-of-x), which wasn't the solution needed.

Thanks for your time and help you can offer.

**Edit 1 - A little more information**

I think what would solve my problem is if I could get the `pchip` function just to interpolate my data between to set points a max and min. As TryHard pointed out maybe the data is been interpolated outside the data which has been defined causing instabilities. 
I know that I can interpolate within a certain range as I demonstrated above but I want to be able to do this and generate the `X` values given the `Y` values in the vector `r`

Comment: In your last code snippet, using `angle=pchip(x,Y,xi);` works for me... what exactly is wrong with the result? You do realize that the `x` must come before the `y` in the parameters right?

Comment: My best guess is that you are applying an interpolation function to *extrapolate*: note that the values r>Y. This probably is resulting in instabilities. Do you want to extrapolate from your (x,y) data? Perhaps if you can explain more clearly your general objective?

Comment: @Dan Yes using `angle=pchip(x,Y,xi);` works ok but does not give me the output i need as i want it to give a sample of results size `r` as shown in my first code section. Also I have `X` and `Y` in the order that I need, to get the correct results.

Comment: Correction: most samples r<y

Answer (score 1):

Try constraining the values of `r` to the observed range of `y`:

```
samples=10;
y=[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1];
x=12.5:45:327.5;

r=rand(samples,1)*(max(y)-min(y)) + min(y);
angle=pchip(y,x,r);
```